# Find tax bracket using SQL, without a min and max field

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select a tax bracket in SQL.

I could simply make a minbracket and and maxbracket feild, but it would be duplicate data.

Currently, I have:

```
SELECT s1.statetaxid, s1.statecode, s1.type, s1.taxrate, s1.bracket, s1.exemptperfiler, s1.exemperdependent, s1.deductfederaltaxonstate
FROM
    statetax s1
    INNER JOIN  statetax s2
        ON s1.statetaxid = s2.statetaxid - 1
WHERE                     
    s1.statecode  = 'NY' AND
    s1.type = 'Single' AND
    s1.bracket <= 300000 AND
    s2.bracket > 300000
```

Which works great for 300,000 but not whenI get to the highest tax bracket of NY because I am looking for a s2.statetaxid to be "under", but not for say 1,000,000.

```
statetaxid  statecode   type  taxrate bracket exemptperfiler  exemperdependent  deductfederaltaxonstate
107         NY        Single   0.0400       0           7700                 0                     1000
108         NY        Single   0.0450    8200           7700                 0                     1000
109         NY        Single   0.0525   11300           7700                 0                     1000
110         NY        Single   0.0590   13350           7700                 0                     1000
111         NY        Single   0.0645   20550           7700                 0                     1000
112         NY        Single   0.0665   77150           7700                 0                     1000
113         NY        Single   0.0685  205850           7700                 0                     1000
114         NY        Single   0.0882 1029250           7700                 0                     1000
```

How can I include the case where a salary is above the highest threshold?

Comment: i you can do it using an easier method, what is the need for this question?

Comment: Actually it's not necessarily easier, I'll run into the same problem of checking for a tax ceiling when there isn't one. I would just have duplicate data.  This way, I just have less tables.  The where logic is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you start at 0, you want to find the row with the MAX bracket less than your salary:

```
SELECT s1.statetaxid, s1.statecode, s1.type, s1.taxrate, s1.bracket, s1.exemptperfiler, s1.exemperdependent, s1.deductfederaltaxonstate
FROM
    statetax s1
WHERE                     
    s1.statecode  = 'NY' AND
    s1.type = 'Single'   AND
    s1.bracket = (
      select max(s2.bracket)
      FROM
        statetax s2
      WHERE                     
        s1.statecode  = s2.statcode AND
        s1.type = s2.type           AND
        s2.bracket < 300000 -- salary?
      )
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a better solution, and much cleaner than where I was going